# angular-chart.js graph not displaying on Ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, charts

I am using angular-charts in my ionic app but the graph does not seem to render.

Here is the Markup Code:

```
 <ion-view title="Home" hide-nav-bar="false" ng-controller="checkUserInfoCtrl">
 <ion-content padding="true">
   <ion-item >  
    <canvas id="doughnut" 
       class="chart chart-doughnut"
       chart-data="data" 
       chart-labels="labels">
    </canvas> 
   </ion-item>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Here is the controller code:

```
angular.module("app", ["chart.js"]).controller("checkUserInfoCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.labels = ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"];
$scope.data = [300, 500, 100];
});
```

Any Ideas on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic','chart.js'])
    .controller('myController', [function() {
        var ctrl = this;
        ctrl.socialChart = {
            options: {
                legend: {
                    display: true
                }
            },
            labels: ["Download Sales", "In-Store Sales", "Mail-Order Sales"],
            colors: ['#ED402A', '#F0AB05', '#A0B421', '#00A39F'],
            data: [300, 500, 100]
        };

    }]);

})(window.angular);
```

**[`DEMO`](https://plnkr.co/edit/QMcjDMUJJQZHS6Xr9aPk?p=preview)**